# typed.js - Calling custom function before each new string using preStringTyped

Tags: callback, typed.js

Trying to fire a custom function before each new string is typed. Would like the strings to loop, use smart backspace, and be SEO friendly. Is this possible?

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/bmess/qcpfs4n9/1/

**HTML**

```
<h1 id="typed-strings" class="page-title">
  <span>Built to be Autonomous.</span>
  <span>Built to be Reliable.</span>
  <span>Built to be Portable.</span>
  <span>Built to Last.</span>
</h1>
<h2 class="h1 page-title">
  <span id="typed"></span>
</h2>
```

**JS**

```
var typed = new Typed("#typed", {
  stringsElement: '#typed-strings',
  typeSpeed: 50,
  backSpeed: 10,
  backDelay: 2000,
  smartBackspace: true,
  loop: true,
  loopCount: false,
  preStringTyped: function(index, self) {
    alert(index);
   // Fire custom function here
 },
});
```

Code above should throw alert before the typing of every new string is started.  It loops through with smart backspacing however it's not trowing an alert before each new string is typed out.  Any ideas?